# undefined method `insert' for RegistrationInsert:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

I'm trying to call a method I defined in `registration_insert.rb` from my controller but I keep getting the following error:

> > undefined method `insert' for RegistrationInsert:Class

How do I correctly call the insert method?

File Structure (all under /app)

-controllers

---------registrations_controller.rb

-registrations

---------registration_insert.rb

registrations_controller.rb:

```
 def create
    @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
    RegistrationInsert.insert(registration_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration.save
        format.html { redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @registration }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

registration_insert.rb

```
module RegistrationInsert 
    def insert(registration)
        #method code
    end
end
```

Edit: Changed class to module and it gives me this error:

> undefined method `insert' for RegistrationInsert:Module

Comment: Is `registration_insert.rb` a model?

Comment: No it's just a helper class I made

Comment: If its a helper, shouldn't it be `module RegistrationInsert`?

Comment: I still get the same error - `undefined method `insert' for RegistrationInsert:Module`. I'll update my post with what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need just `RegistrationInsert.new.insert`?

P.S. Please consider to make `RegistrationInsert` a class, not module. Classes are better for service objects realization.

P.P.S. If you want `RegistrationInsert.new`, then add `self.` before the method:

```
module RegistrationInsert 
  def self.insert(registration)
    #method code
  end
end
```